# Linq to Entities in EF4 using generated POCO classes

Tags: entity-framework

I used the ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator Visual Studio add-in to generate POCO classes for my entities.

When I try to use the class in a Linq to Entities query such as the one below:

```
var q = from w in entities.Widgets
        select new Widget
        {
            Id = w.Id,
            WidgetName = w.WidgetName,
            WidgetDescription = w.WidgetDescription
        };


return q.ToList();
```

I get the following exception:

"The entity or complex type MyNamespace.Widget' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

The only way around this is to use an anonymous type and then another LINQ query:

```
var q = from w in entities.Widgets
        select new
        {
            Id = w.Id,
            WidgetName = w.WidgetName,
            WidgetDescription = w.WidgetDescription
        };

var r = from e in q.AsEnumerable()
        select new Widget
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            WidgetName = e.WidgetName,
            WidgetDescription = e.WidgetDescription
        };

return r.ToList();
```

This works but is pretty redundant.  I understand why I'm getting the exception, but is there a more elegant way around this?

The fact that the POCO classes are generated by the ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator doesn't seem related to the issue; I tried using my own POCO classes and saw the same exception.

Many thanks.

EDIT:
Added link to walkthrough for using the ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator Visual Studio add-in - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing `MyNamespace.Widget` is a custom class - and not part of the EDM?

If so, you can't project a LINQ-Entities query into a custom type. Doesn't matter if your using POCO's or not.

You've got the right idea projecting to an anonymous type.

You can shape the query on the client once you have **materialized** the query on the server:

```
var widgets = entities
               .Widgets
               .ToList() // materialize query
               .Select(x => new Widget
                       {
                          Id = w.Id,
                          WidgetName = w.WidgetName,
                          WidgetDescription = w.WidgetDescription
                       }
               ).ToList();
```

Which is a bit nicer than your workaround.

But this begs the question - why aren't you returning the "Widget" type on the EDM in the first place?

The whole point of POCO's is so you can seperate the persistence-logic into simple classes. So i'm not sure why your projecting from a simple type (POCO), to *another* (seemingly identical) simple type. Are you mapping your POCO's to DTO's for N-Tier transport?

Comment: RPM1984, I'm not creating new POCOs in addition to the ones that are already created in the EDM. The ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator add-in takes the entities out of ModelName.Designer.cs and generates a context class and a separate POCO for each entity. It also removes the EdmEntityTypeAttribute attribute from the classes, which I guess effectively removes them from the EDM.

Comment: Forgot to add, I do intend to return List<Widget> from a REST service running in Azure so I will be mapping them to DTOs.  Thanks

Comment: Once you generate the POCO's, you should not *need* the designer.cs file. Maybe there is a conflict happening here. Did you set "Code Generation Strategy" to **none** once you generated the POCO's? You should not have a designer.cs file with POCO's - only the EDMX.

Comment: Correct, the Designer.cs file is empty. Sorry if that wasn't clear in my comment.

Comment: Okay - good. Now, `select new Widget` is that the same class that is contained in `entities.Widgets` ? Or are they seperate classes?

Comment: Yes, it is the same class. I do feel that something is missing though, all the EF "glue" is gone - I don't see how the classes that the add-in generated could work for this purpose.

Comment: If they're the same class, why are you projecting then? (`select new`) Just do: `var widgets = entities.Widgets.ToList()`.

Comment: I get it now ... If I wanted to get the query results into a DTO class, I would use the technique in your code snippet. Otherwise, I don't need to project.  Thanks for walking me through this.

Comment: @George Durzi - exactly. `.Select` or `select new` is for *projecting* the type in EF into some other type. You'll need to do this when your projecting into DTO's. As i said, just make sure you materialize the query (.ToList) before projecting.

Answer (score 2):

This [page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/f24f88f4-fc0d-4da3-bb4e-7bbb8377f05b/) suggests that it's because you're creating an Entity object outside the scope of the Entity Framework, which is apparently not allowed. They are essentially using the same workaround as you, by double-selecting the result from the anonymous type after the initial select.

If this were me, I'd probably avoid all of this by simply selecting `w` and be done with it, or creating a new special View type class to accommodate for the specialisation of Widget. Hopefully there's a better answer than this :)